# ArcGIS API for JavaScript - access data inside analysing widget (interpolatePoints)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, widget

[My code so far (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/obrob/0evLafhz/)

I want to analyse weather data. I am trying to create a Webmap Application to do so. The App should be based on the [JavaScript API 3.18](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/) provided by ArcGIS online. Implemented should be an analysing widget provided by the JavaScript API with the functionality of [interpolatePoints](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/interpolatepoints-amd.html)

I am not able to load the data into widget. I am using a [featureLayer](http://muenchh.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9f8a66287d464b31be608bf5f44e128e#overview) which i am able to visualize on the map as a layer. But I am not able to connect the widget with the datas inside the layer.

Some other details:

- I am working on 'localhost'.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Analysis</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
    html,
    body,
    #border-container {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .esriAnalysis .esriAnalysisCloseIcon {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "esri/urlUtils","esri/Color", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/analysis/InterpolatePoints",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
    ], function(ready, parser, urlUtils, Color, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleRenderer, Map, FeatureLayer, InterpolatePoints) {
        ready(function() {
            parser.parse();

            var map = new Map("map", {
                center: [13, 55],
                zoom: 6,
                basemap: "dark-gray"
            });

            var pointLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/01Gk9ODQDPg4NrOx/arcgis/rest/services/WU_Data/FeatureServer/0");

            map.addLayers(pointLayer);

            var marker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
                "color": [238, 69, 0, 125],
                "style": "solid",
                "size": 8,
                "outline": {
                    "color": [255, 255, 255, 125],
                    "width": 0.5
                }
            });
            var rendererA = new SimpleRenderer(marker);
            pointLayer.setRenderer(rendererA);
            map.addLayer(pointLayer);

            var analysisTool;

            analysisTool = new InterpolatePoints({
                inputLayer: pointLayer,
                portalUrl: "http://analysis.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/tasks/GPServer",
                map: map,
            }, "toolPane");

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: edited my question, so it's focusing on the main problem so far.

Comment: I think you should still try to ask a specific question rather than just describing a problem but I can see that you have been editing so I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: It may be blocked because 1) the map is hosted on HTTPS while the CSV comes from HTTP ("mixed content"), or 2) CORS: your map is hosted on another (sub-)domain than the CSV and `arcgis.com/sharing/...` does not provide the HTTP headers to allow you to request that data. Check your browser's developer tools (F12) for any network related errors

Comment: it does indeed show me a network error: "Esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl has not been set. When you send a request to a CORS-enabled server, move the domain to esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers." I am running my webapp on localhost. I am not sure how to proceed now. . .

Comment: Please continue to [edit] your question with any details that are likely to help potential answerers.